# How to resolve "key not found: :ciphers"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm *very* rusty with rails and I think a lot has changed in the 7-ish years since I've worked with it.

I'm trying to set up this sample app: https://iridakos.com/news/2015/06/21/rails-sample-api-ui

The problem I'm facing is that the UI doesn't interact with the API correctly. I get the error in the screenshot below.

The lofocats UI app gives me the following stack trace:

```
KeyError (key not found: :ciphers):
  lib/api/resource.rb:39:in `execute'
  app/models/cat_entry.rb:46:in `all'
  app/controllers/cat_entries_controller.rb:9:in `index'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:44:in `set_api_authentication_token'
```

line 44 in application_controler.rb is the first line of the begin block (`Api::Configuration.current_authentication_token = session[:user_information][:authentication_token] if is_user_signed_in?`):

```
def set_api_authentication_token
  begin
    Api::Configuration.current_authentication_token = session[:user_information][:authentication_token] if is_user_signed_in?
    yield
  ensure
    # Always nullify the token after each action.
    Api::Configuration.current_authentication_token = nil
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how to get around this error. I've not seen it before and searching SO gives some Cloudinary specific answers.

[image: screenshot of error]

Answer (score 5):

#### Upgrade your `rest-client` gem to `>= 2.0.1`.

This issue had to do with a newer version of `OpenSSL` and it was fixed in `rest-client` gem version 2.0.1, as per this Issue comment:

https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/612#issuecomment-313034465

So just make sure you are using 2.0.1 or greater of `rest-client` and you should be all good. We statically set ours to `2.1.0`, which was the latest stable release at the time of writing, and everything is running smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

Just answering 9 years later as this was one of the only threads I found on this issue.  In my case, using Unirest and RestClient both gave me the error in the title, despite my calls working from the command line with Curl.  I switched to the HTTParty gem, and no more errors.

Inferring from a discussion on RestClient's Github, this may be because RestClient and Unirest "check for weak default TLS ciphers", due to older versions of Ruby not having a "sane cipher list".

https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/pull/573

Comment: ha this was actually from Apr 10 of this year (not April 2010)! But I also changed jobs and am no longer working on this. :-)

Comment: Ha!  More current than I thought.  Sorry, still too late for you!

Comment: No need to change gems. Just upgrade your `rest-client` gem to `>= 2.0.1`, where this issue was fixed: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/612#issuecomment-313034465

Answer (score 2):

How do you interact with API? Are you using some gem? I've got similar message error when i was using outdated `rest-client` gem. Updating from `1.X` to `2.X` solved issue.

`` NoMethodError (undefined method `response' for #<KeyError: key not found: :ciphers>) ``

Maybe some gem using outdated `rest-client` gem? This was my issue(if i recall correctly), i forked repo and updated dependency

Comment: all of the code lives here: https://github.com/iridakos/lofocats_ui and https://github.com/iridakos/lofocats_api - this is not my code just a sample app that i'm trying to get running locally

Comment: To be specific, this was fixed in version `2.0.1` of the `rest-client` gem so make sure you upgrade to at least that version. The latest published version (at the time of writing) is `2.1.0`, which worked great for us.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like an error commonly thrown by older versions of the `rest-client` gem. The error is discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/612).

If your project is dependent on `rest-client`, you should upgrade to v2.0.1 or better.

If your project does not depend directly on `rest-client`, chances are one of your other dependencies does. Try running something like this and see what you get:

```sh
gem dependency -R | grep -B 3 rest-client
```

If you discover any top-level dependencies that depend on `rest-client`, you can update those and see if that resolves the issue.

If one of your dependencies is up-to-date but still using an outdated version of `rest-client`, the maintainers of that dependency will need to update their `rest-client` version. Check their list of known issues to see if a bug report has been filed. If not, you can be the first to let them know that they need to update!

If you must continue to use an older version of `rest-client`, there are two known workarounds. You can set a default ciphers argument which will apply globally:

```rb
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::DEFAULT_PARAMS[:ciphers]=OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new.ciphers;
```

Or you can add the following option to individual requests:

```rb
ssl_ciphers: RestClient::Request::DefaultCiphers
```

Ref: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.8.0/RestClient/Request