# Rails Ubidots Ruby gem: key not found: ciphers not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use [Ubidots ruby gem](https://github.com/ubidots/ubidots-ruby) and every time I try to access a page where I make use of it I get a "key not found: :ciphers" error, similar to this one: [How to resolve "key not found: :ciphers"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55616274/how-to-resolve-key-not-found-ciphers/56549614)

How can I fix this?
Thanks